# Linq Query to Get Distinct Records from Two Tables

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, linq-to-sql, inner-join

I have two Tables - tblExpenses and tblCategories as follows

## tblExpenses

```
ID (PK),
Place,
DateSpent,
CategoryID (FK)
```

## tblCategory

```
ID (PK),
Name
```

I tried various LINQ approaches to get all distinct records from the above two tables but not with much success. I tried using UNION and DISTINCT but it didnt work.

The above two tables are defined in my Model section of my project which in turn will create tables in SQLite. I need to retrieve all the distinct records from both the tables to display values in gridview.

Kindly provide me some inputs to accomplish this task. I did some research to find answer to this question but nothing seemed close to what I wanted. Excuse me if I duplicated this question.

Here is the UNION, DISTINCT approaches I tried:

## DISTINCT #  ==> Gives me Repetitive values

```
(from exp in db.Table<tblExpenses >()
                                   from cat in db.Table<tblCategory>()                                       
                                   select new { exp.Id, exp.CategoryId, exp.DateSpent, exp.Expense, exp.Place, cat.Name }).Distinct();
```

## UNION #  ==> Got an error while using UNION

Comment: Show us what you tried with UNION and DISTINCT as that is the right path.

Comment: If union doesn't work, maybe you could try [Linq ZIP](http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cnagel/2010/02/linq-with-net-4-zip.html) and Distinct

Comment: The main problem is that you create a Cartesian Product or cross-join (`from exp ... from cat ... select`).

Answer (score 3):

I think union already does the distict when you join the two tables you can try somethin like

```
 var query=(from c in db.tblExpenses select c).Concat(from c in 
            db.tblCategory select c).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: I just tried your approach. I get an error saying 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<SQLiteSample.Models.PurchaseExpense>' does not contain a definition for 'Concat' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Concat<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx  might be just rrelated to sql lite

Answer (score 1):

You will always get `DISTINCT` records, since you are selecting the `tblExpenses.ID` too. (*Unless there are multiple categories with the same ID. But that of course would be really, really bad design.*)

Remember, when making a `JOIN` in LINQ, both field names and data types should be the same. Is the field `tblExpenses.CategoryID` a nullable field?

If so, try this `JOIN`:

```
db.Table<tblExpenses>()
.Join(db.Table<tblCategory>(), 
       exp => new { exp.CategoryId }, 
       cat => new { CategoryId = (int?)cat.ID }, 
       (exp, cat) => new { 
                           exp.Id, 
                           exp.CategoryId, 
                           exp.DateSpent, 
                           exp.Expense, 
                           exp.Place, 
                           cat.Name 
                         })
.Select(j => new { 
                   j.Id, 
                   j.CategoryId, 
                   j.DateSpent, 
                   j.Expense, 
                   j.Place, 
                   j.Name 
                 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this queries:
A **SELECT DISTINCT** query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM tblCategory INNER JOIN tblExpenses ON tblCategory.categoryID = tblExpenses.categoryID;
```

limits the results to unique values in the output field. The query results are not updateable.

or


A **SELECT DISTINCTROW** query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW Name FROM tblCategory INNER JOIN tblExpenses ON tblCategory.categoryID = tblExpenses.categoryID;<br/><br/>
```

looks at the entire underlying tables, not just the output fields, to find unique rows.

reference:http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/query/distinct_vs_distinctrow/unique_values_records.asp